# Laravel router problem when I use Route::any

Tags: laravel

I would appreciate any help you could give me with the following problem I have.
I am trying to implement a Single Page Application (SPA) with Laravel and Vue, at the moment I am defining the routes, I have something like the following:

**routes/app.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::any('{path}', function () {
        return view('index');
    });
});
```

What I'm trying to do here is the following:

1. For the middleware `web` you will only have one view available, in this case in the file `index` in **(resources/views/index.php)**
2. I want that regardless of the method used, Laravel returns the view I want. But I have not succeeded.

Output of `php artisan route:list`

[image]

And when I try to verify with `Postman` I receive a `404` in response regardless of the method or the URL that I requested .. what could I be doing wrong? Thank you very much in advance.

[image]

***EDIT 1***

I have modified my router and added a conditional as follows:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::any('{path}', function () {
        return view('index');
    })->where('path', '.*');
});
```

Now the `GET` and `HEAD` method work properly, however ... when I try the `POST` method, I get the following error ..

[image]

**EDIT 2**

As mentioned @lagbox in the comments below, error `419` refers to `missing CSRF token`. I could disable this check in the file `Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`.

However I wish I could just return the desired view .. without first checking the `CSRF token`. Another detail that I find is the following:

When in `Postman` I make a request by a method different from the typical methods ... let's say `UNLINK` method, I get the following result:

[image]

Which leaves me a bit confused, when I define in my routes file `web.php` `Route::any`, does it mean any route or not?

Comment: the 419 is because of the verify csrf token middleware that is in the 'web' group

Comment: @lagbox Thank you very much for the clarification. Do you have any idea how to implement this type of behavior? I mean, I'm just going to use web middleware to display a login page, and only for that. How could I get the CSRF token to not verify for that specific middleware?

Comment: Route:any means any request method, post and get being the most common methods

Comment: @bumperbox and how I can capture any another method?